# Sequelize count return value is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm updating the dependencies for an Express app written with TypeScript from `sequelize` version 4 to version 5. Version 5 has built in type support and the project additionally uses the `sequelize-typescript` package.

One build error I can't quite figure out how to fix from the docs occurs anywhere the `.count()` method is called on a model:

```
const quantity: number = await MyModel.count();
```

> Type '{ [key: string]: number; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.

It seems like count should simply return a `number` type but I'm not sure why the `[key: string]:` is there or how to work with it...

Answer (score 0):

The return value is different if the query includes the `group` option:

[sequelize/types/lib/model.d.ts](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/b3d28490dc1d91473c795137201625aade3e3873/types/lib/model.d.ts#L1796)

```
  /**
   * Count number of records if group by is used
   */
  public static count(options: CountWithOptions): Promise<{ [key: string]: number }>;

  /**
   * Count the number of records matching the provided where clause.
   *
   * If you provide an `include` option, the number of matching associations will be counted instead.
   */
  public static count(options?: CountOptions): Promise<number>;
```